# Tomcat not stopping

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using hibernate to query PostGre DB to fetch data.
the hibernate configuration is:
        true

```
    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->
    <property name="c3p0.initialPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxPoolSize">1000</property>

    <property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property> <!-- seconds -->

    <property name="c3p0.acquireIncrement">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxStatements">0</property>
```

I am setting environment variable in tomcat as:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/jingdb" auth="container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="10000" validationQuery="select 1"
        username = "test" password="test" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://<IP>:5432/jing_users">
```

But when I am closing tomcat, I am not able to close it, although I am closing all my session object in dao by calling:

```
session.close()
```

After calling shutdown.sh if I type

ps -ef|grep java I am getting:

```
root     13199     1 49 22:54 pts/0    00:00:29 /usr/share/java-1.7.0/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -DJING_CONFIGURATION_FILE_LOCATION=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/authenticationweb/WEB-INF/classes/keystore.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this document:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-stop-tomcat-6-0-a-940165/

It says:

If you edit shutdown.sh you will see it calls catalina.sh with the parameters you pass to shutdown.

You can try with:

```
./shutdown 5 -force
```

to force stop tomcat if it doesn't stop in 5 seconds.

To know if the instance is running, you can configure the variable CATALINA_PID.
It's recommned to create a file in called $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh (and set +x permission) where you define the variables:
Example:

```
export ANT_HOME=/opt/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java6
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat6"
export CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_BASE"
export CATALINA_TMPDIR=$CATALINA_BASE/temp
export CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_HOME/run/tomcat6-instance1"
The setenv.sh is read automatically when starting and stopping tomcat.
```

You will have to create the $CATALINA_HOME/run directory.

If you want to know if tomcat is up,

```
ls $CATALINA_HOME/run
```

will list the instances which are up.